AWS Amplify: cannot access an attribute in the user object, but the attribute does exist
In src/index.js, Amplify is initiated as below:
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    storage: browserStorage,
    authenticationFlowType: 'CUSTOM_AUTH', 
  },
});

In src/app.jsx,

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';


const App = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('NotChecked');
  const [userGroups, setUserGroups] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log('storage.organizationId: ', result.storage.organizationId);
        console.log(' == Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() result: ', result);
        setCurrentUser(result);
        const groups =
          result.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload['cognito:groups'];
        setUserGroups(groups);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setCurrentUser('NotSignedIn');
      });


In the console log:
result.storage.organizationId is undefined;
However, result contains storage, which then contains organizationId key and the value is an integer;
How can this be possible?
organizationId is set in local storage in a grand children component of the App component.
